# $L^{\infty}$ estimate for heat equation with $L^2$ initial data

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, parabolic-pde, semigroups-of-operators

Is there a way to show in a relatively simple manner that for a Lipschitz bounded, connected, open domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ for any $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ the solution of the problem:

$$\begin{cases}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\Delta u, & (t,x)\in (0,T)\times \Omega\\ \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}=0, & (t,x)\in (0,T)\times\partial\Omega \\ u(0,x)=f(x), & x\in\Omega\end{cases}$$

is bounded and $\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}\leq c\cdot t^{-N/4}\cdot \Vert f\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}$ for any $t\in (0,T)$, for some $c$ depending only on $\Omega$?

Comment: Use the integral representation in terms of the fundamental solution?

Comment: Is there such a formula taking into account the Neumann bc?

Comment: This can be proved by Nash inequality, as explained in the book of Ouhabaz, Analysis of heat equations in domains

Comment: In Theorem 6.3 and 6.4 this inequality in Ouhabaz (page 158) this inequality is equivalent with proving that $\Vert u\Vert^2_{\frac{2d}{d-2}}\leq c\cdot a(u,u),\ \forall u\in D(a)$. But this is not true in our case since $a(u,u)=\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u |^2\ dx$ and $D(a)=H^1(\Omega)$. For example $u=$constant do not satisfy such an inequality.

Comment: Moreover, since Theorem 6.4 is an equivalence, we can say that the inequality from the statement is false. The same can be deduced from Theorem 2.4.6 in DAVIES -  HEAT KERNELS AND SPECTRAL THEORY. But that contradicts other resources, such as Arendt-Semigroups and Evolution Equations: Functional
Calculus, Regularity and Kernel Estimates, page 69 where it is stated that Neumann Laplacian on Lipschitz domains is ultracontractive (i.e. satisfies the inequality in the statement). It's very hard for me to decide where is the truth...

Comment: One has to be a bit careful here, there a two (non-equivalent) forms of ultracontractivity. The one holds for the heat semigroup on full space and requires the $L^1$-$L^\infty$ bound from the question for all $t\geq 0$. As noted in Denis' answer, this cannot possible hold for the Neumann Laplacian on bounded domains. The second form of ultracontractivity requires the $L^1$-$L^\infty$ bound from the question only on bounded intervals with a constant $c$ *depending on $T$*. This form of ultracontractivity is true for the Neumann Laplacian on bounded domains with Lipschitz boundary.

Comment: The equivalent characterization in terms of a Sobolev inequality takes the form $\lVert u\rVert_{2d/(d-1)}^2\leq c(a(u,u)+\lVert u \rVert_2^2)$, which is true for bounded domains with Lipschitz boundary.

Comment: As explained by @MaoWao one has to apply Ouhabaz results to the form $a+1$ which gives global ultracontractivity to for the scaled semigroup and local for the original one.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inequality is obviously false, because if $f\equiv c$ is a constant, then $u\equiv c$ remains constant. Since $\Omega$ is bounded, this $f$ is $L^2(\Omega)$, and yet $\|u(t)\|_\infty=|c|$ does not decay as $t\to+\infty$.

I suppose that you make a confusion with the heat equation in the hole space ($\Omega={\mathbb R}^N$, of course the boundary condition disappears). Then
$$u(t)=H_t\star f$$
where the heat kernel is given by
$$H_t(x)=\frac1{(2\pi t)^{N/2}}K\left(\frac x{\sqrt t}\right),\qquad K(y):=\exp\frac{-|y|^2}4.$$
From Young inequality (or just Hölder)
$$\|u(t)\|_\infty\le\|H_t\|_2\|f\|_2=\frac c{T^{N/4}}\|f\|_2.$$

Turning back to the case of a bounded domain, the general rule is an exponential decay as $t\to+\infty$. For instance, the spectrum of $\Delta$ under the Dirichlet boundary condition $u|_{\partial\Omega}=0$ is real, bounded above by $-\mu_D<0$, and we get $\|u(t)\|_p=O(e^{-\mu_D t})$ for every $p\ge2$. In the case of the Neumann boundary condition, we must subtract the mean of the initial data:
$$\|u(t)-\frac1{|\Omega|}\int_\Omega f(x)dx\|_p=O(e^{-\mu_N t}),\qquad\forall p\ge2.$$
Here $\mu_N$ is the least non-zero eigenvalue of $-\Delta$.